# Laplace transform of a non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I don't understand how to to write the answer of this problem in in the form $$ A\frac {1}{s-1}+ B\frac {1}{s+1} + C\frac {1}{s+2} $$ depicted in this problem:

[image: problem]

Comment: You must review partial fractions. Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYHIAsAMqoc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\big\{5y'''+11y''-5y'-11y&=e^{-2t}\big\}\\
5\left[s^3 Y(s)-s^2 y(0)-s y'(0)-y''(0)\right]+11\left[s^2 Y(s)-s y(0)-y'(0)\right]
-5\left[sY(s)-y(0)\right]-11Y(s)&=\frac{1}{s+2}.
\end{align*}
Continuing:
\begin{align*}
5\left[s^3 Y(s)-1\right]+11s^2 Y(s)-5sY(s)-11Y(s)&=\frac{1}{s+2}\\
Y(s)\left[5s^3+11s^2-5s-11\right]&=\frac{1}{s+2}+5\frac{s+2}{s+2}\\
Y(s)\left[5s^3+11s^2-5s-11\right]&=\frac{5s+11}{s+2}\\
Y(s)&=\frac{5s+11}{(s+2)(5s^3+11s^2-5s-11)}\\
&=\frac{5s+11}{(s+2)(s-1)(s+1)(5s+11)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(s+2)(s-1)(s+1)},\quad\text{for}\; s\not=-11/5.
\end{align*}
Next, you assume, via partial fractions, that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(s+2)(s-1)(s+1)}
&=\frac{A}{s-1}+\frac{B}{s+1}+\frac{C}{s+2}.
\end{align*}
The most straight-forward way to get $A,B,$ and $C$ is to get the common denominators on the RHS, and equate the same powers of $s,$ thus giving you three equations in three unknowns. However, in this case, the [Heaviside cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) will give you the results much faster. We have, in fact, that
\begin{align*}
A&=1/6\\
B&=-1/2\\
C&=1/3.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much @AdrianKeister